# .Net Apple Push Notification service Provider?

Tags: iphone, sockets, ssl, push, apple-push-notifications

I started to write a provider for APNs in .Net today, and it seems I've hit a brick wall...

Everything I'm finding about securing sockets says that a System.Net.Sockets.Socket cannot implement SSL.  I'm fairly new to raw sockets programming...does anyone know of a way to connect a raw socket to a server over SSL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [apns-sharp](http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/). I've done some experimenting with Push Notifications, and was able to get the server side of things up and running with that in very little time at all. (Even if you don't use it as-is, the source may help you.)

Comment: I notice the developer(s) used a TCPClient object in stead of a plain socket, which makes sense.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This library (apns-sharp) has been greatly improved/fixed since this was posted, I encourage you to check it out!

Comment: follow all the links for @Redth and you get to https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you don't need to use open source things for achieving that if you have serious or critical project instead you can use a professional push notification provider.

I like this guys, they are making realy different things then others. Check-out [MonoPush](http://www.monopush.com) project 
Note : Don't forget that users very sensitive you don't have to make mistake.